# longest substring, time limit exceeded java

Tags: java, string, algorithm

Given a string, find the length of the longest substring without repeating characters. For example, the longest substring without repeating letters for "abcabcbb" is "abc", which the length is 3. For "bbbbb" the longest substring is "b", with the length of 1.

```
public static int lengthOfLongestSubstring(String s) {
    if (s.length()==0)
        return 0;
    int maxlen = 1;

    HashMap<Character, ArrayList<Integer>> check = new HashMap<Character,ArrayList<Integer>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < s.length(); j++) {
            if (!check.containsKey(s.charAt(j))) {
                ArrayList<Integer> value= new ArrayList<>();
                value.add(j);
                check.put(s.charAt(j), value);
            }
            else {
                maxlen = Math.max(j - i, maxlen);
                ArrayList<Integer> temp = check.get(s.charAt(j));
                i=temp.get(temp.size()-1);  
              // get the last index(biggest index) of the key value
                check.clear();
                break;
            }
            if(j==s.length()-1) {
                maxlen = Math.max(j - i + 1, maxlen);
            }

        }
    }
    return maxlen;
  }
}
```

For the last test of long repeatable string, time limit exceeded. Do not know how to optimize. seek for improvement, thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to calculate? Some comments in your code may be helpful and the title is missleading.

Comment: How do you expect us to work out what this code is supposed to do if you don't comment to code or describe the inputs and outputs. We could guess I suppose - but that would be far from productive.

Comment: Why is the longest non-repeatable `String` `3`? What's the logic here?

Comment: That is unclear. Largest non-repeatable string is always full string.

Comment: But what has all this to do with time limit exceeded? Whats the time limit anyway?

Comment: sb. finished in O(n)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a fairly simple solution which should be quicker that your solution:

```
public static int longestNonRepeating(final String s) {
    final Set<Character> unique = new HashSet<>();
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
        final char c = s.charAt(i);
        if (!unique.add(c)) {
            for (int j = i - unique.size(); j < i; ++j) {
                if (s.charAt(j) != c) {
                    unique.remove(s.charAt(j));
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        max = Math.max(max, unique.size());
    }
    return max;
}
```

How does this work?

We walk along the `String` and add characters to a `Set`. If the character we add is already contained in the `Set` then we know that we have a duplicate in the current substring.

In this case, starting from the beginning of the current substring (which must be the same length as the size of `unique`) we walk along. If we find a character that isn't the duplicate we found, the duplicate must be further along, we keep searching.  As soon as we find the duplicate we can stop searching.

To sort of visualise the process:

```
a  b  c  a  b  c
0  1  2  3  4  5
^
|
i
```

we have `a` in our unique `Set`.

```
a  b  c  a  b  c
0  1  2  3  4  5
   ^
   |
   i
```

we have `a,b` in our unique `Set`.

```
a  b  c  a  b  c
0  1  2  3  4  5
      ^
      |
      i
```

we have `a,b,c` in our unique `Set`.

```
a  b  c  a  b  c
0  1  2  3  4  5
^        ^
|        |
j        i
```

We try to `add` `a` to the unique `Set`, it's a duplicate. From the start of the unique substring, try and find an `a`. Luckily this is at `0`, we don't need to remove anything from unique.

```
a  b  c  a  b  c
0  1  2  3  4  5
   ^        ^
   |        |
   j        i
```

We try to `add` `b` to the unique `Set`, it's a duplicate. From the start of the unique substring, try and find an `b`. Luckily this is at `1`, we don't need to remove anything from unique.

```
a  b  c  a  b  c
0  1  2  3  4  5
      ^        ^
      |        |
      j        i
```

We try to `add` `c` to the unique `Set`, it's a duplicate. From the start of the unique substring, try and find an `c`. Luckily this is at `1`, we don't need to remove anything from unique.

And we're done. The longest unique substring is `3`.

Comment: It is O(N) - at most N steps forward + at most N steps "backward". I've posted the same algorithm, but you're faster and better looking implementation.

Comment: This is a really nifty solution (+1). You can make it slightly quicker/nicer in two ways. 1) By replacing the `HashSet` by a `HashMap<Character, Integer>` storing last index of each `Character`. Then instead of `if (!unique.add(c))` you can do `if ((k = unique.put(c, i)) != null)`, and you then know the exact range of characters you need to remove, without the need for that `break`. 2) Also it can be `else max = Math.max...`.

Comment: @pbabcdefp I don't follow your first suggestion - knowing the index of the character from which I need to clear does not help - I still need to know _which_ characters to remove and that would still require me to loop from the start of the current substring to that point. As far as I can see, the `Map` is a red herring. I don't much like the second suggestion either - it won't make much, if any, difference and adds lines of code.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Adding the single word `else` does give a slight improvement in performance. However I was completely wrong about the `Map`. I only realised hours later the correct way to use a `Map` - see my answer.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Following your comment that an optimized version would be better I added an optimized version to my answer. Have a look on it and tell me your opinion.

Comment: @pbabcdefp how did you benchmark - did you use [jmh](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) or similar? Otherwise the results of the benchmark are unlikely to be meaningful.

Answer (score 2):

Find below an optimized version. The enhancement compared to the initial version:

- it doesn't create additional objects
- it does not duplicate any character, it works on the string data itself
- it reduces the number of comparison steps

**edit2** I upload a JMH benchmark [here](https://gist.github.com/SubOptimal/7ca3fd194f0d17b75f5c) which compares the algorithms from three answers to this question. Direct link to the [benchmark result](https://gist.github.com/SubOptimal/7ca3fd194f0d17b75f5c#file-benchmark-log).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] strings = {"abcabcdebb", "abcbacde", "abb", "bba",
        "cbaabc", "abccba", "xabccba", "abcxcba", "abccbax",
        "", "a", "aa", "ab"
    };
    for (String s : strings) {
        System.out.printf("string: %-10s   maxSubStringLength: %d%n", s,
            maxSubStringLength(s));
    }
}

static int maxSubStringLength(String string) {
    if (string.isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    }
    int maxLength = 1;
    int low = 0;
    for (int high = 1; high < string.length(); high++) {
        for (int pos = high - 1; pos >= low; pos--) {
            if (string.charAt(pos) == string.charAt(high)) {
                low = pos + 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        maxLength = Math.max(maxLength, high - low + 1);
        if (string.length() - low <= maxLength) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return maxLength;
}
```

**how does it work**

- we keep a pointer to the most left character `low`
- we increase the pointer of the right character `high` till maximum to the length of the string
- if we have increased the `high` pointer we search backwards if the most right character (the one at position `high`) occurs in the substring from index `low` till `high`
- if it not occurs

  - we update or keep maximum length, depending if the current selected substring is longer then the previous found maximum length
- else

  - we move the left character index to the position after the left occurence
- if the remaining substring length to test is not longer then maximum length, we can stop the checks already at this point
- continue with the second bullet point

**initial post, to see the evolution of the code**

A quite pragmatic solution could be

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "abcabcbb";
    int maxLength = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = i+2; j <= s.length(); j++) {
            String substring = s.substring(i, j);
            if (hasNoDupeChars(substring) && substring.length() > maxLength) {
                System.out.println("substring = " + substring);
                maxLength = substring.length();
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("maxLength = " + maxLength);
}

private static boolean hasNoDupeChars(String substring) {
    Set<Character> chars = new HashSet<>();
    for (Character c : substring.toCharArray()) {
        if (!chars.add(c)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

**edit** As mentioned by Boris there a still optimizations possible. I will not do it here following Donald E. Knuth: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil." ;-)

Comment: You can fix the code of ` hasNoDupeChars` to return as soon as a duplicate is found. You should also reuse the `Set`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Beside the `fail fast` I did no other change in the proposed solution.

Comment: It is one of my most hated things when people misuse that Knuth quote. This is not what Knuth meant. There is never an excuse for lazy coding. Maybe read [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil) at least before ever using it again.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I don't agree with you in this point. We don't know the concrete requirements. We don't know how often this function is called, how long the strings are, what kind of characters they could contain etc. If we know that facts than we can go for an optimized solution. It was not requested to find a solution which creates as least as possible objects or the smallest bytecode. I prefer always to start with a code everybody can follow. Especially if it's a proposal, where many different solutions are possible.

Comment: @BoristheSpider just followed your link. Seems I'm not that wrong. ;-)

Comment: I've been testing all these algorithms to destruction. Your new version technically has worst case time complexity `O(n^2)` (if the `String` has no repeats then you have to search all the way back to `0` for every character). However for long `Strings` with characters from a small set (eg `{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'}`) it often comes out on top. (+1)

Comment: @pbabcdefp Even you use a string with character set containing all characters from 'a-z' I believe there is no other way to find if the character was already found between `low and high` than to compare it with all characters in this range. Taken 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' - till `z` we need to compare each character with each previous one. Taken 'abcdefghijklmnoopqrstuvwxyz' - till first `o` we also need to compare each character with each previous one. On the second `o` we can stop there can't be a longer substring. I don't see how another algorithm could handle such case more efficient.

Comment: I agree with @pbabcdefp on this one. The new algorithm is less _efficient_ than the old - it might be faster with small input but performance will degrade.  The key point is that the `Set` based algorithms utilise **memoisation** to _remember_ which characters they have seen and only backtrack when they _know_ there is a duplicate - this backtracking can never result in walking backwards over the array more than once. Your new algorithm has **no memory** so must backtrack **over the entire `String`** to check for duplicates with each new character. It certainly isn't `O(n)`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider The `Set` keeps all actual unique characters seen so far. To check if the next character is already in the set, it must traverse all entries in the set. My solution keeps the unique characters between `low` and `high` to check if the next character was already seen it checks only the characters between `low` and `high`, the same as the set does. Or do I miss something there?

Comment: @SubOptimal **absolutely not**. Checking `contains` on a `Set` is **guaranteed** to be `O(1)`. i.e. it is constant time, and therefore unrelated to the size of the `Set`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I agree partially. For me this `unrelated to the size of the Set` isn't true. If a set has 10 elements then it's guaranteed to be `O(1)` also for a set of 100 elements. But the time in both cases differ. I did some benchmarking (will put it later on github). I gues we are back to Knuth: We don't know how often the method is called and how the strings to process are structured. For me it makes no sense to spent time in optimisation and (probably) loosing readablity of the code only to reduce the execution time from 2 ms to 0.001 ms. Anyway for me it was an interesting topic.

Comment: Assuming perfect hashing, which would be true for a `char`, the _same amount of time_ would be required for a `contains` of a `Set` of size `1` or a `Set` of some `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (not that there are that many characters). This isn't related to Knuth in the slightest. The quote never advocated writing algorithms with far higher complexity that possible. The OP wants an `O(n)` algorithm. This isn't that.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with time complexity `O(n)`. It is likely to be faster than other solutions here for two reasons.

1. It only compares the length of a chain of distinct consecutive characters with the current maximum when the chain is broken, or when the end of the `String` is reached.
2. By keeping track of the last index of every character rather than
   the set of characters in the substring, there is never any reason to
   remove any elements. This does of course mean that it uses a lot of memory if the `String` has many different characters.

   ```
   public static int subStringLength(final String s) {
       final Map<Character, Integer> indices = new HashMap<>();
       int max = 0;
       int start = 0;
       final int length = s.length();
       for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
           Integer k = indices.put(s.charAt(i), i);
           if (k != null && k >= start) {
               max = Math.max(max, i - start);
               start = k + 1;
           }
       }
       return Math.max(max, length - start);
   }
   ```

Comment: I like this, it's very tidy. There is certainly a memory <-> speed tradeoff here, and of course your could end up storing the entire `String` twice in the worst case, but it _should_ certainly be faster. In reality you only save a single iteration over the `String` as compared to [my approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29660514/2071828) - but that might make a difference in performance critical situations. Would be interesting to see a proper benchmark.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Please see my second edit in my answer. I uploaded a JMH benchmark on github.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved in O(N) where N is length of the string.

Algorithm:

1) Iterate over characters of string. Keep track of last occurrence of each character. At each letter store how far away was previous same character.
E. g.: Having string "abccdae", we would get list [1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 5, 7]. Note that if character hasn't occurred before we set it to length to the beginning of the word.

2) Lets call that list we have gotten V (in example V = [1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 5, 7]).

3) Define function f(x), which calculates the longest word without repeating character that ends at index x.

It holds that:
f(0) = 0
f(x) = min(f(x-1)+1, V[x]), x > 0

4) Iterate over word and calculate f at each index.

5) Find maximum of f.

Each step is O(N), but if you play around you can do all of them at the same time, improving even constant.

Hope this helps.